# filter/sum values, not sure how to implement clojure

Tags: clojure

I am trying to "pivot" the below data, although even trying this in excel it doesn't seem to work.  I am not sure on if I have the logic right.  basically I need to convert dataset a to dataset b.

A

DATE    MEDAL   VALUE1  VALUE2  VALUE3  VALUE4

2013-03-08  SILVER  0   6052    0   0

2013-03-04  BRONZE  0   0   0   0

2013-03-04  BRONZE  0   0   0   0

2013-03-04  BRONZE  0   0   0   0

2013-03-04  BRONZE  0   1437    0   0

2013-03-01  BRONZE  0   0   240 0

2013-03-01  SILVER  0   0   0   0

2013-03-01  BRONZE  0   0   0   0

2013-03-01  BRONZE  0   173 0   0

2013-03-08  SILVER  0   0   0   271

2013-03-04  SILVER  0   2547    0   0

2013-03-04  BRONZE  0   495 0   0

2013-03-04  GOLD    279 0   0   0

2013-03-02  SILVER  0   0   0   0

2013-03-01  BRONZE  0   0   0   0

2013-03-01  SILVER  0   0   0   0

2013-03-01  BRONZE  0   0   0   0

2013-03-01  BRONZE  0   20  0   0

2013-03-03  SILVER  0   0   0   0

B

MEDAL   VALUE1  VALUE2  VALUE3  VALUE4

BRONZE  0   2125    240 0

GOLD    279 0   0   0

SILVER  0   8599    0   271

So basically I'm trying to group-by MEDAL and sum each value column based on the MEDAL filter (MEDAL is variable, could be PURPLE, BLUE etc).  The below attempt is completely wrong, I am reusing some previous code so its probably round peg square hole territory, but I am not sure how to go about this even logically it is confusing me now... :(

Any help or advice would be much appreciated

```
(defn- create-summary [data]
(->> data


     (group-by :MEDAL)
     vals
     (map 
        (fn [recs]
            (let [a (fn [b] (+ (filter #(= b(:MEDAL%)) recs)recs))]
                {:MEDAL (:MEDAL (first recs))
                 :VALUE1sum (a :MEDAL)
                 :VALUE2sum (a :MEDAL)
                 :VALUE3sum (a :MEDAL)
                 :VALUE4sum (a :MEDAL)

                 })))

        ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(def data [{:medal "silver" :v1 1 :v2 2 :v3 3}
           {:medal "gold" :v1 1 :v2 2 :v3 3}
           {:medal "silver" :v1 1 :v2 2 :v3 3}
           {:medal "bronze" :v1 1 :v2 2 :v3 3}
           {:medal "bronze" :v1 1 :v2 2 :v3 3}
           {:medal "gold" :v1 1 :v2 2 :v3 3}])

(->> data
     (group-by :medal)
     (map (fn [[k v]] [k (apply merge-with + (map #(dissoc % :medal) v))]))
     (into {}))

==> {silver {:v1 2, :v2 4, :v3 6}, gold {:v1 2, :v2 4, :v3 6}, bronze {:v1 2, :v2 4, :v3 6}}
```

Comment: Can you paste your data list?

Comment: Sorry, it needs to be a hash map thats why I am getting the null pointer. System only displays data in hash maps - so {:medal silver, :v1 2, :v2 4, :v3 6}
{:medal gold, :v1 2, :v2 4, :v3 6}
{:medal bronze, :v1 2, :v2 4, :v3 6}

Comment: (->> data (group-by :medal) (map (fn [[k v]] (into {:medal k} (apply merge-with + (map #(dissoc % :medal) v))))) ) ) - this works, although I need to figure a way to remove the null values in the actual dataset

Answer (score 0):

I think merge-with will be the key to a  neat solution.

Given that your data is in a vector, something like this:

```
(def medal-values
 [["2013-03-08" "SILVER" 0   6052 0   0]
  ["2013-03-04" "BRONZE" 0   0    0   0]
  ["2013-03-04" "BRONZE" 0   0    0   0]
  ["2013-03-04" "BRONZE" 0   0    0   0]
  ["2013-03-04" "BRONZE" 0   1437 0   0]
  ["2013-03-01" "BRONZE" 0   0    240 0]
  ["2013-03-01" "SILVER" 0   0    0   0]
  ["2013-03-01" "BRONZE" 0   0    0   0]
  ["2013-03-01" "SILVER" 0   0    0   0]
  ["2013-03-01" "BRONZE" 0   0    0   0]
  ["2013-03-01" "BRONZE" 0   173  0   0]
  ["2013-03-08" "SILVER" 0   0    0   271]
  ["2013-03-04" "SILVER" 0   2547 0   0]
  ["2013-03-04" "BRONZE" 0   495  0   0]
  ["2013-03-04" "GOLD"   279 0    0   0]
  ["2013-03-02" "SILVER" 0   0    0   0]
  ["2013-03-01" "BRONZE" 0   0    0   0]
  ["2013-03-01" "SILVER" 0   0    0   0]
  ["2013-03-01" "BRONZE" 0   0    0   0]
  ["2013-03-01" "BRONZE" 0   20   0   0]
  ["2013-03-03" "SILVER" 0   0    0   0]])
```

You could achieve the transformation you need as follows:

```
(defn count-medals
      [medal-counts]
      (merge-with #(map + %1 %2)
                (reduce (fn [agg [_ k & counts]] (merge-with
                                                 #(map + %1 %2)
                                                 agg {k counts})) {} medal-counts)))
```

The result is:

```
(count-medals medal-values)

=> {"GOLD" (279 0 0 0), "BRONZE" (0 2125 240 0), "SILVER" (0 8599 0 271)}
```

There's bound to be a nicer way to collapse it down a little, but hopefully this will put you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Convert data to the following structure:

```
(def data [{:BRONZE [0 495 0 0]}
       {:GOLD [0 0 55 0]}
       {:BRONZE [0 134 0 0]}
       {:SILVER [0 348 0 0]}
       {:SILVER [764 0 0 0]}])
```

and

```
(apply (partial merge-with #(map + %1 %2)) data)
```